# How can I create a window where my program draws a dot ( which is point.png here ) wherever I click on the screen?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

```
import pygame

#Initialise pygame

pygame.init()

#Create the screen

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1200,800))

#Change the title and the icon

pygame.display.set_caption('The Thoughtful Minds')
icon = pygame.image.load('IA.png')
pygame.display.set_icon(icon)

#Dots

dot = pygame.image.load('point.png')

class Dot:
    def update(self):
        self.cx, self.cy = pygame.mouse.get_pos()

    def draw(self):
        screen.blit(dot,(self.cx-8 , self.cy-8))

dots = [Dot() for i in range(5)]

sticking_image = False
i = 0
#Running the window

running = True
while running:
    screen.fill((20,20,20))
    mp = pygame.mouse.get_pos()

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
        elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            dots[i].update()
            sticking_image = True

    if sticking_image:
        for i in range(i):
            dots[i].draw()
        i += 1

    pygame.display.flip()

pygame.quit()
quit()
```

When I run my program it says, 'Dot' object has no attribute 'cx'
I really don't know how to fix this 
Please help

What I mainly want to do is to create a screen that allows the user to draw a dot wherever he clicks in the screen.
I mean multiple dots, I don't need just one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a constructor to the class `Dot` and remove `update`:

```py
class Dot:
    def __init__(self, pos):
        self.cx, self.cy = pos

    def draw(self):
        screen.blit(dot,(self.cx-8 , self.cy-8))
```

Create an empty list of `dots`:

```py
dots = []
```

Create a `Dot` object at the current mouse position and add it to the list of `dots`, when the mouse button is pressed:

```py
running = True
while running:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
        elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:

            # append a new dot at the current mouse position 
            dots.append(Dot(event.pos))

    # clear the display 
    screen.fill((20,20,20))

    # draw all the dots
    for d in dots:
        d.draw()

    # update the dispalay
    pygame.display.flip()
```

[image]

Comment: but after editing the code I still receive an error that says : argument 1 must be pygame.Surface, not Dot

Comment: @manaaarab Sorry, my fault. It has to be `for d in dots:` `d.draw()`. See the answer, I've changed it right now. (I've reused the variable `dot`, this has caused the error)